# Creating a React Button Component, Importing it and adding Text to the Button

Tags: reactjs, button, components

so I am trying to create a re-usable React Button Component that I can import into other Components.

I created the Component, exported it, and imported it into my other Component where I want to use it.

Now if I use `<Button>TEXT</Button>` inside of my other Component, the TEXT does not appear. I am a React noob, obviously.

**React Button Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
    width: 138px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #5DA7DE 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #00000066;
    opacity: 0.86;
    color: white;
`;

export const ButtonBlue = () => {
  return (
<Button/>
  );
};
```

**React Component where I want to use the Button:**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { ButtonBlue as Button } from '../Buttons/ButtonBlue.jsx'

const Container = styled.div`
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
`

export const LandingBottomLatestEvents = () => {
    return (
    <Container>
        <Button>TEXT</Button>
    </Container>
    )
}
```

Checked Google but couldn't find a solution so far.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you write something between a tag

```
<Component>Hello World</Component>
```

You can get this using a **children** props in Component

```
const Component = ({children}) => {
  console.log('children', children) // Hello World
  return <h1>{children}</h1>
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That works! But you have to use the keyword 'children', right? I tried it with {text} and that didn't work.

Comment: Yes @StefanRows, props.children